# Porque o deploy com PHP é mais simples?

Tags: php, deploy, comparação

eu estou com a seguinte duvida, porque o deploy com PHP é mais simples do que com outras linguagens, como PYTHON ou RUBY?

eu sei que tem muitas *stacks* prontas, mas quando é para subir uma aplicação desse tipo numa VPS por exemplo, é tão mais trabalhoso?

isso tem a ver com a maneira na qual a linguagem foi construída?

Answer (score 4):

### ASP.NET e PHP

PHP é uma linguagem quase que totalmente dedicada a web e o PHP roda "embarcado" junto ao HTML, outras linguagens são basicamente linguagens, o que elas manipulam é o input e output, no caso o output é o que vai gerar as página e rotas.

Então no PHP ao menos na maioria dos servidores quando você requisita algo como `http://site/pagina.php` o Apache/IIS/Ngnix (fast-cgi, fpm, etc) vai passar os dados do input pré-tratados para o PHP manipular em suas variáveis e qualquer coisa que escrever no PHP com `echo`, `print` ou até mesmo escrever um HTML diretamente será considerado "output" que no caso é gerar uma resposta no formato "HTTP", basicamente porque o PHP foi projetado para fazer isto mesmo, apesar de existirem muitos frameworks PHP que mudam um pouco o comportamento.

Então básicamente é só pegar o conteúdo e soltar na pasta `htdocs`/`public_html`/`www` se for PHP.

Se tratando de C# o que é usado para web é a *"plataforma"* asp.net, ele é quase como o PHP, é possivel criar páginas com alguns códigos "embarcados" no meio do HTML que tudo será processado como resposta HTTP e ainda é possivel escrever alguma coisa na classe principal que fica "por trás", no asp.net-mvc é diferente porque segue uma certa arquitetura um pouco mais complexa e não posso afirmar como é, no geral a linguagem roda lado a lado com os arquivos `.aspx` ou com o controle da resposta no `Response` ainda sim o *deploy* é fácil em IIS (servidor semelhante ao Apache usado principalmente para páginas em asp.net e afins) pois é quase subir para a pasta via *FTP* ou soltar na pasta principal do servidor se tiver acesso.

### Outras linguagens e "plataformas"

Linguagens como Ruby e Python e programas como Node.js não interagem com Web diretamente, elas usam módulos, frameworks e plataformas que fazem a linguagem se comunicar com o servidor, na prática poderíamos dizer que o PHP também faz a mesma coisa, mas a diferença esta em como trata o "output", estas linguagens não trabalham de modo "embarcado" com o conteúdo html/txt/etc, elas fazem a intermediação do que é recebido e processam a resposta

> nota no caso do Rails o framework escrito em Ruby é o que faz a parte "web", apesar de existirem outros framework menos populares

Por exemplo em Python para se "escrever" um resposta HTTP teria que fazer algo assim (fonte: <sup>https://wiki.python.org/moin/BaseHttpServer</sup>):

```python
import time
import BaseHTTPServer

HOST_NAME = 'localhost'
PORT_NUMBER = 80

class MyHandler(BaseHTTPServer.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(s):
        """Resposta HTTP para o GET"""
        s.send_response(200)
        s.send_header("Content-type", "text/html")
        s.end_headers()
        s.wfile.write("<html><head><titleTeste</title></head>")
        s.wfile.write("<body><p>Isto é um teste.</p>")
        s.wfile.write("<p>Você acessou: %s</p>" % s.path)
        s.wfile.write("</body></html>")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server_class = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer
    httpd = server_class((HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER), MyHandler)
    print time.asctime(), "Servidor iniciou - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)

    try:
        httpd.serve_forever()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    httpd.server_close()
    print time.asctime(), "Servidor parou - %s:%s" % (HOST_NAME, PORT_NUMBER)
```

Basicamente foi escrito um servidor em Python, claro que isto é um exemplo bem mais complexos, em Python existem frameworks o modulo WSGI que faz usar python com Apache (fora que é possivel usar o CGI), mas esta é a parte considerada difícil configurar o módulo WSGI com teu framework e fazer os apontamentos necessários, claro que muitos servidores que oferecem suporte para Python já tem isto no *Cpanel da vida* e claramente você deve contratar um serviço que suporte isto.

Outro exemplo é o *Node.js* que é um software para rodar JS sem browser, ele costuma ser usado para servidores, todavia ao fazer isto (usando Express):

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Olá mundo!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Exemplo de servidor local na porta 3000!')
})
```

Apenas criamos uma porta para acesso local como `http://localhost:3000/` para se configurar para um servidor mais completo geralmente é feito o uso de proxy-reverso com *Nginx* (talvez existam outras maneiras), o mesmo poderia ser aplicado ao exemplo com Python.

### Respondendo

> isso tem a ver com a maneira na qual a linguagem foi construída?

Não necessariamente com a linguagem, mas sim com a aplicação toda, no caso o *interpretador PHP* foi construído assim, dando suporte para Web e linha de comando (CLI)

> mas quando é para subir uma aplicação desse tipo numa VPS por exemplo, é tão mais trabalhoso?

Depende muito de como o servidor é, tem servidores que já é tudo pronto basta acertar um ou outro detalhe, geralmente apenas apontar a porta local, como *3000* ou em caso do Python com WSGI apontar o local do teu arquivo `.wsgi` por exemplo `/home/user/projeto1/hello.wsgi` (nestes dois casos supondo que exista um painel de configuração)

### Concluindo

O que torna PHP e ASP.NET mais fácil de fazer o deploy

- PHP junto ao Fast-cgi ou FPM ou Apache2handler são feitos para trabalhar com o servidores populares conhecidos como Apache, Nginx, IIS e Lighttpd e então basta soltar na pasta denominada como "root" que os scripts serão interpretados como páginas após processarem através do "apache"+"modulo"+"interpretador php".
- ASP.NET é uma plataforma própria para web, e também basta "soltar" os arquivos na pasta deseja (não estou falando necessariamente de asp.net-mvc)

Outras linguagens/plataformas não são "WEB", elas são apenas linguagens que são interpretadas ou compiladas, então geralmente é necessário configurar algo como o proxy-reverso que citei anteriormente e isto muitas vezes é feito manualmente.

Claro que dependendo do serviço que contratar eles tem caminhos mais fáceis, como simplesmente apenas aporta a porta local que você vai usar e o resto eles já estão configurados.